# Where is opcache default cache directory?

Tags: php, opcache

According to my phpinfo(), opCache is enabled but I can't find where are located the temp files.

I'm asking because I would like to verify the size of the cache and if it's "too much", I could clear it.

I'm using VestaCP on Debian 9.

Comment: The opcache manages itself and you shouldn't try to insert yourself into that process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the cache size should not be a problem for my VPS?

Comment: The largest it could ever be is as the sum of all `.php` files in your application, and even then it will be a fraction of that.

Answer (score 4):

It’s a memory cache, there’s no folder! You can clear it with opcache_reset if I remember correctly. There shouldn’t be any need to watch out for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before, I was on a shared hosting (now on a VPS) and there was a folder .opcache at the root with lots of files in it. When I wanted to clear it, I deleted what was inside the folder.

Comment: Yeah, shared Hosters.